# Would a forward slash cause issues with StringUtils.remove and .removeEnd?

Tags: java, android, string, substring, apache-stringutils

I'm extracting a piece of text from a webpage using JSoup and cleaning up the resulting string with Apache's StringUtils library. The first pass, using `substringBetween` to grab just the text in parentheses works like a charm, returning a string (`value`) of digits followed by units (e.g., 2500mg/kg).

But when I try to drop the trailing units (mg/kg) using `removeEnd`:

```
value = StringUtils.removeEnd(value, "mg/kg");
```

... I always get back the original string completely unchanged -- 2500mg/kg.

I tried using just plain `remove` and `removeEndIgnoreCase` (just in case), but I couldn't get anything to work.

First I tried this as an alternative:

```
value = value.substring(0, value.indexOf("m"));
```

... and that worked for a couple of tests and then failed(??). So then I tried:

```
value = StringUtils.substring(value, 0, -5);
```

This seems to be working fine, but I'm not wild about it since it isn't specific about what it's removing. I would really prefer to use `removeEnd` (or something similar) here (plus I'm new at this, so I always want to know **why** something doesn't work).

Can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong? I couldn't find any restrictions on special characters in the StringUtils docs, but could the forward slash be causing an issue? Or should I be worrying about invisible control characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me (with commons-lang3-3.7.jar):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String value = "2500mg/kg";
    System.out.println (StringUtils.removeEnd(value, "mg/kg"));
}


2500

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Are you sure your original string ends with mg/kg? Dump the contents of the string to sysout before your attempted removeEnd, or check the value using the debugger.

If you suspect there's a control character at the end, you could use another commons-lang utility to display the string:

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(value)
```

Comment: I have a logcat statement that shows the string is definitely coming in to `removeEnd` as "2500mg/kg" -- based on your suggestion, I edited it to use `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava` and also wrap the output in single quotes (to be sure there weren't any trailing space characters).

Comment: Well, I retyped the line using `removeEnd`, and it's now working. Looking back at my version history, it looks like I boneheadedly forgot to reassign the variable (the line was _only_ `StringUtils.removeEnd(value, "mg/kg");` without `value =`! So embarrassing! Thank you for your suggestion, which forced me to rubber duck it.